# Create a database with php, blank pages?

Tags: php, mysql

So trying to make a database with php, however if I run my code I get just blank pages in both Firefox and Chrome?

Is there something I have to do in order to make php work?

```
    <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

if (mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE my_db",$con))
  {
  echo "Database created";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error creating database: " . mysql_error();
  }

mysql_close($con);
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is that a php file? Are you using Xampp and if so is Apache and MYSQL services running? done

Comment: Start using mysqli

Comment: a *blank page* means something is broken. Add these lines `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the top of your PHP script and see if it yields any error or not.

Comment: Also, don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed altogether in PHP 7.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`pdo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. [And this is why you shouldn't use mysql_* functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: if youre using PHP7 the mysql driver is gone.

Comment: @William Madede yes borh apache and mysql are running I made sure to check phpadmin to confirm

Comment: @Rajdeep Paul still blank

Comment: When you echo something does it display..?done.

Comment: @WilliamMadede using <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php
echo "hello"
?> 
</body>
</html> I get a blank page still

Comment: Are you sure you are running a .php file?done

Comment: @WilliamMadede I solved thanks to Ruchish Parikh, I was running the file from my desktop, not from htdoc ..... really stupid mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mysqli_connect()`. Don't use mysql_* functions, they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed.

Try below.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

if (mysqli_query($con,"CREATE DATABASE my_db1"))
  {
  echo "Database created";
  }


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: **_already fixed!_** [You may want to check out this line `die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());`]

Comment: dont forget the one in the die statement

Comment: correct, edited. Thanks. @C0dekid

Comment: @Ruchish Parikh not working, blank page also <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");

if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
  }

if (mysqli_query($con,"CREATE DATABASE my_db1"))
  {
  echo "Database created";
  }


mysqli_close($con);
?>


</body>
</html>

Comment: I have checked on my system its working fine and i got message `"Database Created"`. Please check with error reporting. @Ausghostdog

Comment: add this line and check error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: @RuchishParikh still blank

Comment: have your page in .php extension or not? @Ausghostdog

Comment: @RuchishParikh nope and there is my issue, trying to run it from my desktop. Thanks for the help.